# Random forest regression severely overfits single variable data

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, modeling, random-forest

I am trying to use sklearn's random forest regression for a toy example. I generated 500 uniform random numbers between 1 and 100 as the predictor variables, and then took their logs and added Gaussian noise to form the response variables.

I've heard that random forests typically work well out of the box, so I was expecting a reasonable looking curve, but this is what I got:
[image]

I don't understand why the random forest seems to hit each data point. Because of bagging, each tree is missing some fraction of the data, so when all of the trees are averaged it seems like the curve should be more smoothed out, and not hit the outliers.

I'd appreciate any help in understanding why this model overfits so much.

Here's the code I used to generate the plot:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_design_matrix(x_array):
    return x_array.reshape((x_array.shape[0],1))

N = 1000

x_array = np.random.uniform(1, 100, N)
y_array = np.log(x_array) + np.random.normal(0, 0.5, N)

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)

model = model.fit(create_design_matrix(x_array), y_array)


test_x = np.linspace(1.0, 100.0, num=10000)
test_y = model.predict(create_design_matrix(test_x))
plt.plot(x_array, y_array, 'ro', linewidth=5.0)
plt.plot(test_x, test_y)
plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should use `RandomForestRegressor` for regression. And you need to tune the parameters, e.g. `max_depth`, to avoid overfitting.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! Can't believe I was accidentally using the classifier. Using RandomForestRegressor and setting max_depth to 5 gives a reasonable looking model. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a regression problem, not classification.

If you have as many classes as samples, a decision tree will fit it,
for me this is not an overfit.
If you think this is an overfit, you may reduce the depth of the decision tree.

Comment: The point "this is a regression problem, not classification" is correct. But since it is a regression problem, there is nothing to do with "have as many classes as samples".